# I need help. First time writing C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, indexing, function-definition

Can someone help me fixing the syntax errors in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int result(int v, int size);

int main(void){
    int arr[5], n;
    for (n = -1; n < 4; n++){
        arr[n] = n + 1;
        printf("the product of entered values is %d", result(n, 5));
    }
    return 0;
}

int product(int a[]) {
    int product, i;
    for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(int); i++){
        product *= a[i];
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: If you are getting errors then please show them in the post. And have you searched for those errors? Often just pasting the entire error into a search engine will bring up posts with relevant info on how to fix it. Finally please format your code with consistent spaces and indentation to make it readable.

Comment: Compilation failed due to following error(s)./tmp/ccKrYzlA.o: In function `main':
/home/main.c:20: undefined reference to `result'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Arrays start at 0, not -1.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67011578/edit) your post with that info as it forms part of the question.

Comment: New programmers tend to think that formatting of the code is not important. That is not true. It is *extremely* important. It allows to see the program structure and even spot different errors. In the form it is currently presented it is simply not readable. *Upd*: Note the edit. See the difference?

Comment: So where is `result`?

Comment: Isn't the error self explanatory? You are calling `result` but have not provided any definition of that function. Is it defined somewhere else you have not shown?

Comment: @kaylum args don't match params:(

Answer (score 1):

```
for (n = -1; n < 4; n++){
    arr[n] = n + 1;
```

You start `n` at `-1`, then immediately use `arr[n]`.

Negative indices are not allowed in C.  Valid values are `0` to the `size of the array-1`.
In otherwords, if you have an `arr[5]`, then the valid indices are `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`, and `[4]`.

---

```
int product(int a[]) {
    int product, i;
```

You create a function named `product` and also a variable named `product`.
That makes it virtually impossible to refer to the proper object.   Work on your name management, so that every item is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the result function, for which you have provided the forward declaration but not an actual implementation. You need to write an implementation for the result function. That is why the compiler complains about an undefined reference.

Comment: Im sorry, of course I was talking about the result function. Will edit!

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
 int result(int v[], int size);

 int main(void) {

 int arr[5], n;

 for (n = -1; n < 4; n++)
 arr[n] = n + 1;

printf("the product of entered values is %d", res(v, 5));
 return 0;
}

int result(int a[]) {

 int product;
 for (i = 0; i <= a.length, i++)
 product *= a[i];

 return total;
 }

Comment: this is the original code with all the syntax error

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function `result` is declared

```
int result(int v, int size);
```

but not defined.

On the other hand, taking into account the message in this call of `printf`

```
printf("the product of entered values is %d", result(n, 5));
```

you mean a function that calculates a product of elements of an array like your function defined after `main` but that is not used

```
int product(int a[]) {
    int product, i;
    for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(int); i++){
        product *= a[i];
    }
    return product;
}
```

So let's remove the declaration of the function `result` and declare before main a function with name `product` because the name `result` is not enough informative.

The function deals with an array. We need to pass to the function the number of elements in the array. As the array itself will not be changed within the function then it should be declared with the qualifier `const`

Also a product of integer numbers of the type `int` can be too big to be stored in an object of the type `int`.

So it is better to declare the return type of the function at least like `long long int` (or even like `double` or `long double`).

Thus the function declaration can look like

```
long long int product( const int a[], size_t n );
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
long long int product( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    long long int result = n == 0 ? 0 : 1;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        result *= a[i];
    } 

    return result;
}
```

As for your function `product` then you forgot to initialize the variable `product`

```
int product, i;
```

The condition in the for loop

```
for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(int); i++){
```

does not make a sense because the expression `sizeof( int )` does not yield the number of elements in an array.

Try to not use magic numbers like `5` in this declaration

```
int arr[5], n;
```

in your programs. Use named constants.

Indices of arrays always start from 0. So this loop

```
for (n = -1; n < 4; n++){
```

where the variable `n`  is used as an index does not make sense.

Also this call of printf

```
printf("the product of entered values is %d", result(n, 5));
```

must be placed outside the for loop and in the the call of the function `result` that is used as an argument of the function `printf`

```
result(n, 5)
```

you even are not using the array.

Thus the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int product( const int a[], size_t n );

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 5 };
    int a[N];
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = i + 1;
    }
    
    printf( "The product of entered values is %lld", product( a, N ) );
    
    return 0;
}

long long int product( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    long long int result = n == 0 ? 0 : 1;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        result *= a[i];
    } 

    return result;
}
```

The program output is

```
The product of entered values is 120
```